# Salt stack targeting with respect to absence of user input for some time

Tags: salt-stack

Is it possible in salt stack to only select minions with no user input for some time? For instance, I want to only run command on the minions that have no mouse and keyboard events for at least half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the concepts available in Salt this could be done as [Beacon](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/beacons/), [Mine](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/) or [Schedule](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.schedule.html).

Salt Beacon instructs your minions to send events on special situations. You can use them as part of Salt's Reactor to trigger events. The `ps beacon` or the `sh beacon` might be what you are looking for.

Salt Mine allows you to collect information periodically (default once per hour, but you can also trigger it manually) and use it with `mine.get` in your scripts.

Salt Schedule allows you to trigger command autonomously on the minions.

But I am afraid that there is no predefined functionality to check for user input or inactivity.